# How to assign an event output to a variable?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-invocation, events

I'd like to get the event result in my UI.

Here is my contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;


 contract T2{
 uint public k;
 event CheckVal(uint val);
 function Test() returns (uint){        
  var temp=441;
  CheckVal(temp);
  k=32; 
  return temp;
   }    
}
```

and in the console I have this:

```
var eve=instance.CheckVal();
eve.watch(function(error, result){console.log( 
result.args.val.toNumber());});
```

Every time I run

```
    instance.Test({from:eth.accounts[0],gass:4200000})
```

441 appears in the console, which is right. But I want to get the value (i.e. 441) in my UI, so I want to assign it to a variable.

**Question**: How to assign the output of event log to a variable?

Comment: assign `result.args.val.toNumber()` to your variable?

Answer (score 1):

This question can have a lot of different answers based on what you want to do with the variables (like do you want to overwrite it, or store a growing list of variables that come in through your event?), but the simplest version would be like this.

`var eve=instance.CheckVal();
var storedValue;
eve.watch(function(error, result){
   storedValue = result;
});`

And now if you log out storedValue, it will return 441.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as this:

```
var eventOutput
var eve = instance.CheckVal();
eve.watch(function(error, result){
  eventOutput = result.args.val.toNumber()
});
```

Of course you need to use that output in some way in your frontend to make it visibile, e.g. by saving it in the state if this is a React app.